# Example of a function $f: [a, b] \to \mathbb{R}$ that is unbounded.

Tags: functions

Can anyone give me an example of a function $f\colon[a,b]\to\mathbb{R}$ that is unbounded?

Comment: Dom, you might consider accepting answers to several of your other questions.

Comment: Only if there are answers which are any good! He's only had six questions, it's a bit soon to be drawing conclusions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There can be no continuous function that has that property (since a continuous function defined on a finite closed interval must achieve a maximum and a minimum value, hence must be bounded; or, to use higher power results, the image of a compact set under a continuous function is compact). However, you can define discontinuous functions that do rather easily. E.g,
$$f(x) = \left\{\begin{array}{ll}
\frac{1}{x-a} - \frac{1}{b-x}&\text{if }x\neq a\text{ and }x\neq b\\
0 &\text{if }x=a\text{ or }x=b.
\end{array}\right.$$
This function has $\lim\limits_{x\to a^+}f(x) = \infty$ and $\lim\limits_{x\to b^{-}}f(x)=-\infty$.

Answer (score 5):

Consider the interval $[0,1]$. Define

$f(x) = \begin{cases}
\frac{1}{x} & \quad x \neq 0 \\
0 & \quad x = 0
\end{cases}$

Clearly $f$ is unbounded. Note that $f$ is not continuous.

Answer (score 0):

How about the function whose value is $\tan(x)$ where this is defined, and $0$ whenever $\tan (x)$ is undefined?  Just go for the portion from $[0,\pi]$ to ${\Bbb R}$ if you like.